# Database query works fine outside Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wpdb

This is my code

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `submit_time` AS 'Submitted', max( if( `field_name` = 'Salutation', `field_value` , NULL ) ) AS 'Salutation', max( if( `field_name` = 'First Name', `field_value` , NULL ) ) AS 'First Name', max( if( `field_name` = 'Last Name', `field_value` , NULL ) ) AS 'Last Name', max( if( `field_name` = 'Title', `field_value` , NULL ) ) AS 'Title'
FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits`
WHERE `form_name` = 'Sign Up'
GROUP BY `submit_time`
ORDER BY `submit_time` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 100
");

foreach($rows as $a){
echo $a->field_value;//field value is col name
}
$wpdb->print_error();
?>
```

What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: tried $wpdb->get_var() and it worked , thanks btw.

Comment: I am glad you figured it out. :) Sometimes all it takes is taking a step away and coming back to it to figure it out.

Comment: @PieterGoosen just did :)

Comment: Just remember to come back and accept it as soon as the restriction is lifted :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with different functions , I figure out `$wpdb->get_row()` and `$wpdb->get_var()`
The first one returns rows into an associative array or numerical array , depends on the second argument in `$wpdb->get_row('query',ARRAY_A or ARRAY_N or OBJEECT)` and the second one that I used to solve my problem return only one variable from particular table.
e.g,

```
<?php
$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users" );
echo "<p>User count is {$user_count}</p>";
?>
```

Reference [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is the difference btwn `$wpdb->get_results` and `$wpdb->get_var`, I see your query is working fine after removing `where` clause.

Just know that one thing `$wpdb->get_results` returns an array.

Comment: `$wpdb->get_results()` is more generic `$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );`, i think and it returns rows in an associative array while `$wpdb->get_var()` is specific to get one variable from a table like `<?php
$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users" );
echo "<p>User count is {$user_count}</p>";
?>`
Reference [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Comment: Yeah... that's true, then did you find, what was the reason,`get_results()` is not working with your query, even we have rows in our result-set.